# Unexpected memory allocations when calling functions stored in variables in Julia

Tags: function, memory, julia

I'm encountering an issue in Julia where calling functions stored within a struct leads to unexpected memory allocations, as shown in the code below. Direct function calls (variant 1) don't result in any allocations, but other variants where the function is either stored in a struct or a variable cause allocations of 16 bytes. This impacts the performance significantly. Why does this happen, and how can I avoid these allocations?

```
using BenchmarkTools

mutable struct Foo
  v::Float64
  f::Function
end

function add_one(x::Foo)
  x.v += 1
end

x = Foo(0.0, add_one)

println("variant 1")
@btime add_one(x)
@btime add_one(x)

println("variant 2")
@btime x.f(x)
@btime x.f(x)

println("variant 3")
func = x.f
@btime func(x)
@btime func(x)

println("variant 4")
func1 = add_one
@btime func1(x)
@btime func1(x)

println("variant 5")
func2 = (x::Foo) -> begin x.v += 1 end
@btime func2(x)
@btime func2(x)

println("func = '$func'")
```

output:

```
variant 1
  6.900 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
  6.900 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
variant 2
  61.060 ns (1 allocation: 16 bytes)
  61.122 ns (1 allocation: 16 bytes)
variant 3
  28.414 ns (1 allocation: 16 bytes)
  28.543 ns (1 allocation: 16 bytes)
variant 4
  28.442 ns (1 allocation: 16 bytes)
  28.342 ns (1 allocation: 16 bytes)
variant 5
  27.711 ns (1 allocation: 16 bytes)
  27.739 ns (1 allocation: 16 bytes)
func = 'add_one'
```

Is this problem inherent to Julia's design? Why variant 2 is significantly slower than variants 3-5?

I intend to use variant 2 extensively with simple functions involving just a few operations, which means that I cannot ignore the overhead.

Comment: `add_one` is a *function* but like all Julia functions, it is also a *type*. `add_one` type is a subtype of `Function`. `Function` is an *abstract type* and as such, causes the extra-allocation. The Julian way of avoiding this allocation is to make `Foo` parametric like: `struct Foo{F<:Function} v::Float64; f::F; end`. There is more information in the manual when searching for Function I suppose.

Comment: Also, `x` is global in benchmarking context, you may need interpolation https://juliaci.github.io/BenchmarkTools.jl/stable/manual/#Interpolating-values-into-benchmark-expressions

Comment: Changing the struct definition to `struct Foo{F<:Function} v::Float64; f::F; end` only makes things worse, as variant 1 after applying the change makes 2 allocations of 32 bytes. Rest remains unchanged. Encapsulating `x` variable and benchmarking code within a function also changes nothing.

Answer (score 1):

You need to avoid abstract types:

```
mutable struct Foo2{T <: Function}
    v::Float64
    f::T
end

function add_one(x::Foo2)
    x.v += 1.0 # use the same type of one as the data or use `one(x.v)`
end
```

Now you can do:

```
julia> y = Foo2(0.0, add_one)
Foo2{typeof(add_one)}(0.0, add_one)

julia> @btime $y.f($y)
  2.500 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
500503.0
```

Note that you need to interpolate `y` in tests - otherwise you are measuring the effort for Julia to get the type of `y`.

You could also make it a `const` (and thus make type stable for the benchmark):

```
julia> const z = Foo2(0.0, add_one);

julia> @btime z.f(z)
  2.500 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
```

Last but not least `@btime` can be run just once.